# Selecting multiple objects in sql and seeing if at least 1 has different value?

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is, I need to select multiple items from the database, In a certain date range where in this date range the status is always 0. Lets say `$startdate=28/10/2014` and `$enddate=30/10/2014`

Items in database are like

```
id    date          status   price 
1     27/10/2014    0        10
2     27/10/2014    0        20
3     27/10/2014    0        30
1     28/10/2014    1        10
2     28/10/2014    0        20
3     28/10/2014    0        30
1     29/10/2014    0        10
2     29/10/2014    0        20
3     29/10/2014    0        30
1     30/10/2014    0        10
2     30/10/2014    0        20
3     30/10/2014    0        30
```

I need to select an item between the start date and end date with the status 0 and then group them by id. the sql I use is

```
      SELECT * FROM {base} WHERE date>="'.$startdate.'" AND date<="'.$enddate.'" 
AND status=0 GROUP BY id
```

the problem I run into is that even though the date with the status 1 isnt selected, other 2 dates 29/10/2014 and 30/10/2014 are selected and in group by process I still see the item (id =1 ) that has a status 1 in them in the date range. How do i Check in the sql request (If i can) that the current id doesnt have a status 1 date in the given date range? I'm sorry if my question doesn't make any sense or something, I've been working on this all day and can't think strait anymore

*EDIT*

I solved the problem based on [McAdam331](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3131147/mcadam331) s answer,  by making another request before my request and making an array out of it then checking with `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: If you just want the id's, then just use **select distinct(id)** ?

Comment: My advice is to work step by step. First, try all you requests on you DataBase Manager (like PhPMyAdmin for MySQL). If you directly throw your requests on your php code you may be disturbed by the double difficult : php / sql. 
And as an other advice, try to cut your request : first try to select all the object between two date. When it works, select all the object having status = 0, etc...

Comment: OP, did you get a solution to this?

Comment: yes and sorry for being absent, will update and choose the answer.

Comment: @Guram don't worry about it, I just like to look at unsolved questions I've answered to see if there's still open issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use NOT EXISTS and write a subquery that pulls for rows that have a status of 1 somewhere in the date range.

```
SELECT id
FROM {base}
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM {base}
                 WHERE date >= "'.$startdate.'" AND date <= "'.enddate.'" AND status = 1)
AND date >= "'.$startdate.'" AND date <= "'.enddate.'"
```

You should check for dates in the outer query as well, because you are still only pulling dates from that range.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more condition to your query:

```
SELECT id 
FROM {base} 
WHERE date >= "'.$startdate.'" AND date<="'.$enddate.'" AND status=0 
    AND ID NOT IN(SELECT id 
                  FROM {base} 
                  WHERE date >= "'.$startdate.'" AND date<="'.$enddate.'" AND status=1) 
                  GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want ids whose values are always zero in the data range:

```
SELECT id
FROM {base}
WHERE date >="'.$startdate.'" AND date <= "'.$enddate.'" 
GROUP BY id
HAVING MIN(status) = 0 AND MAX(status) = 0;
```

Comment: I see you everywhere on these MySQL tagged questions and I just have to say I am always impressed by your answers. Quite often I've seen us achieve the same thing only your answers are shorter and cleaner.